# MVC Routing and SiteMap not resulting on correct breadcrumb trail

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, url-routing, asp.net-mvc-routing, mvcsitemapprovider

I'm using MVC.SiteMap, with some success. The only problem arises when I have a 3 steps path (or more). Let me share some of the code to clarify my problem:

After some clean-up, this is my route table:

```
        routes.MapRouteWithName(
            name: "RealizacaoPesquisa",
            url: "RealizacaoPesquisa/{action}/{idPesquisa}/{nrProntuario}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "RealizacaoPesquisa", action = "Index", idPesquisa = UrlParameter.Optional, nrProntuario = UrlParameter.Optional, id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

        routes.MapRouteWithName(
            name: "Geral",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}/{str}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
        );

        routes.MapRouteWithName(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

And this is my SiteMap XML:

```
<mvcSiteMapNode title="Realização de Pesquisas" controller="RealizacaoPesquisa" action="Index">
  <mvcSiteMapNode title="Participação de Pesquisa" controller="RealizacaoPesquisa" action="Participacao" preservedRouteParameters="idPesquisa">
    <mvcSiteMapNode title="Paciente em Pesquisa" controller="RealizacaoPesquisa" action="ParticipacaoPaciente" preservedRouteParameters="idPesquisa;nrProntuario"/>
  </mvcSiteMapNode>
</mvcSiteMapNode>
```

What I expect:

1) When visiting the first page (action = "Index"), it would show `Realização de Pesquisas`.

2) When visiting the second page (action = "Participacao", idPesquisa = 2), it would show `Realização de Pesquisas > Participação de Pesquisas`.

3) When visiting the third page (action = "ParticipacaoPaciente", idPesquisa = 2, nrProntuario = "032"), it would show `Realização de Pesquisas > Participação de Pesquisas > Paciente em Pesquisa`.

Right now, it works except for item 3 (on item 3 it simply won't render anything, taking me to believe that it's not matching any XML node for the siteMap).

EDIT:

Another attempt that rendered the same result, was using the following routes:

```
        routes.MapRouteWithName(
            name: "RealizacaoPesquisa_Participacao",
            url: "RealizacaoPesquisa/Participacao/{idPesquisa}",
            defaults: new { controller = "RealizacaoPesquisa", action = "Participacao" }
        );

        routes.MapRouteWithName(
            name: "RealizacaoPesquisa_Participacao_Paciente",
            url: "RealizacaoPesquisa/ParticipacaoPaciente/{idPesquisa}/{nrProntuario}",
            defaults: new { controller = "RealizacaoPesquisa", action = "ParticipacaoPaciente" }
        );

        routes.MapRouteWithName(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Again, when accessing the first step: `http://localhost:61404/RealizacaoPesquisa` 
everything was good;

when acessing the second step: `http://localhost:61404/RealizacaoPesquisa/Participacao/27`
everything was still ok;

but when I got to the third step: `http://localhost:61404/RealizacaoPesquisa/ParticipacaoPaciente/27/0002642811`
No Breadcrumb trail rendered.

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

You are correct in your assumption that the node does not match the route in this case.

The route

```
routes.MapRouteWithName(
    name: "RealizacaoPesquisa",
    url: "RealizacaoPesquisa/{action}/{idPesquisa}/{nrProntuario}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "RealizacaoPesquisa", action = "Index", idPesquisa = UrlParameter.Optional, nrProntuario = UrlParameter.Optional, id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

has 5 parameters. You are only accounting for 4 of them in your node. When you don't pass an parameter marked as `UrlParameter.Optional` to a route, your route will still contain the route key with a value of `""`.

```
Key     Value

id      ""
```

So, in order for it to match you need to specify it in `PreservedRouteParameters`.

```
<mvcSiteMapNode title="Paciente em Pesquisa" controller="RealizacaoPesquisa" action="ParticipacaoPaciente" preservedRouteParameters="idPesquisa;nrProntuario;id"/>
```

However, your routing is also invalid. Only 1 optional parameter can be used and it must always be the right-most parameter. If you don't do this, then the routing framework won't understand how to build the URL when you leave out an optional parameter that is not the right-most value.

To get the effect (I think) you are looking for, you will need to break it into at least 2 routes.

```
routes.MapRouteWithName(
    name: "RealizacaoPesquisa1",
    url: "RealizacaoPesquisa/{action}/{idPesquisa}",
    defaults: new { controller = "RealizacaoPesquisa", action = "Index", idPesquisa = UrlParameter.Optional }
);

routes.MapRouteWithName(
    name: "RealizacaoPesquisa2",
    url: "RealizacaoPesquisa/{action}/{idPesquisa}/{nrProntuario}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "RealizacaoPesquisa", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Comment: Ok, I posted the one attempt that I thought was the "better one", but I've already tried a lot of other configurations. I'll edit my question to show you another one that fullfill your suggestions...

Comment: And now, I was able to isolate another (very) strange behavior. I can put it to work if using the parameters as "id", "str" (renaming the params on the controller method, on the route parameters and on the preservedRouteParameters on the sitemap XML). Just changing those 3 locations from `idPesquisa` and `nrProntuario` to `id` and `str` makes it works. Putting back the original names render the error described. My mvc.sitemap version is 4.6.15. Any ideas?

Comment: My suggestion is to take a look at what is actually in your `RouteData.Values` dictionary in the request, and compare with the `MvcSiteMapProvider.SiteMaps.Current.FindSiteMapNodeFromKey(<the key>).RouteValues` dictionary. You will need to give the node an explicit key by setting its key attribute. For it to match, all of the keys (case sensitive) and values (case insensitive) of RouteValues must match. Also, have a look at http://www.shiningtreasures.com/post/2013/09/02/how-to-make-mvcsitemapprovider-remember-a-user-position for an explanation of the matching process.